# At least h with at least h

Tags: code-golf, number, array

## Input

A list of nonnegative integers.

## Output

The largest nonnegative integer `h` such that at least `h` of the numbers in the list are greater than or equal to `h`.

## Test Cases

```
[0,0,0,0] -> 0
[12,312,33,12] -> 4
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] -> 4
[22,33,1,2,4] -> 3
[1000,2,2,2] -> 2
[23,42,12,92,39,46,23,56,31,12,43,23,54,23,56,73,35,73,42,12,10,15,35,23,12,42] -> 20
```

## Rules

You can write either a full program or a function, and anonymous functions are allowed too. This is code-golf, so the fewest byte count wins. Standard loopholes are disallowed.

## Background

The [h-index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-index) is a notion used in academia which aims to capture the impact and productivity of a researcher. According to Wikipedia, a researcher has index *h*, if he or she has published *h* scientific articles, each of which has been cited in other articles at least *h* times. Thus, this challenge is about computing the h-index from a list of citation counts.

---

## Update

Wow, great answers all round! I have accepted the shortest one, but if someone else comes up with an even shorter one, I'll update my choice accordingly.

## Winners by language

Here's a table of winners by language that I'll also try to keep up to date. I have included all posts with nonnegative score. Please correct me if I have made a mistake here.

- **APL**: 7 bytes by @MorisZucca
- **Bash + coreutils**: 29 bytes by @DigitalTrauma
- **C#**: 103 bytes by @LegionMammal978
- **C++**: 219 bytes by @user9587
- **CJam**: 15 bytes by @nutki
- **GolfScript**: 13 bytes by @IlmariKaronen
- **Haskell**: 40 bytes by @proudhaskeller
- **J**: 12 bytes by @ɐɔıʇǝɥʇuʎs
- **Java**: 107 bytes by @Ypnypn
- **JavaScript**: 48 bytes by @edc65
- **Mathematica**: 38 bytes by @kukac67
- **Perl**: 32 bytes by @nutki
- **Pyth**: 10 bytes by @isaacg
- **Python**: 49 bytes by @feersum
- **R**: 29 bytes by @MickyT
- **Ruby**: 41 bytes by @daniero
- **Scala**: 62 bytes by @ChadRetz
- **SQL**: 83 bytes by @MickyT
- **TI-BASIC**: 22 bytes by @Timtech

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**APL 7**

```
+/⊢≥⍋∘⍒
```

Can be tried online on tryapl.org

```
f←+/⊢≥⍋∘⍒
f¨(4⍴0)(12 312 33 12)(⍳7)(22 33 1 2 4)(1000 2 2 2)(23 42 12 92 39 46 23 56 31 12 43 23 54 23 56 73 35 73 42 12 10 15 35 23 12 42)
0 4 4 3 2 20
```

Answer (score 12):

## Python 2, 49

Input should be typed in the same format as the examples.

```
i=0
for z in sorted(input())[::-1]:i+=z>i
print i
```

Comment: What an amazing algorithm!

Answer (score 11):

## Python, 52

```python
f=lambda s,n=0:n<sum(n<x for x in s)and f(s,n+1)or n
```

A recursive solution. Run this in [Stackless Python](http://www.stackless.com/) if you're worried about overflows.

Starting from `n=0`, checks whether at least `n+1` of the numbers are at least `n+1`. If so, increments `n` and starts again. If not, outputs `n`.

The conditional is done using Python's short-circuiting for Booleans. The expression `sum(n<x for x in s)` counts the number of values in `s` that are greater than `n` by adding the indicator Booleans, which are treated as `0` or `1`.

For comparison, the iterative equivalent is 2 chars longer. It requires Python 2.

```python
s=input()
n=0
while n<sum(n<x for x in s):n+=1
print n
```

Unfortunately, the input need to be saved for a variable before being iterated over or else Python will try to read the input repeatedly.

Answer (score 11):

## Pyth, <s>13</s> 10 bytes

```
tf<l-QUTT1
```

Input in a form such as `[22,33,1,2,4]` on STDIN.

[Try it here.](http://isaacg.scripts.mit.edu/pyth/index.py)

How it works:

`-QUT` is all of the numbers in the input (`Q`) at least as large as the number being checked, `T`.

`<l-QUTT` is true if the the length of that list is less than `T`.

`f<l-QUTT1` finds the first integer which returns true for the inner check, starting at `1` and going up.

`tf<l-QUTT1` decrements that by one, giving the largest value for which the condition is false, which is the h-index.

Starting at 1 ensures that `0` is returned when the test is always true, such as in the first test case.

Answer (score 9):

## CJam, 15 bytes

Direct translation of my Perl solution.

```
l~{~}${W):W>},,
```

Comment: `l~$W%{W):W>},,` - 14 bytes

Comment: @Optimizer Thanks, I expected there should be a short way of reversing a table. I am surprised though that there is no access to iteration count in maps. Anyway if 1 byte is all you can take that is not bad for my first CJam code.

Comment: There's are some 12-byte solutions now: `{$W%ee::<1b}` (`ee` was added 2015-04-17) and `{$W%_,,.>1b}` (`.` was added 2015-02-21).

Answer (score 6):

## J (<s>13</s> 12)

```
[:+/i.@#<\:~
```

Pretty similar to randomra's solution. Demonstration:

```
   f=:[:+/i.@:#<\:~
   f 0,0,0,0
0
   f 12,312,33,12
4
   f 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
4
   f 22,33,1,2,4
3
   f 1000,2,2,2
2
   f 23,42,12,92,39,46,23,56,31,12,43,23,54,23,56,73,35,73,42,12,10,15,35,23,12,42
20
```

Comment: Using `#\<:` instead of `i.@#<` saves a character.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, <strike>44</strike> <strike>42</strike> <strike>40</strike> 38 bytes

Anonymous function:

```
LengthWhile[i=0;SortBy[#,-#&],#>i++&]&
```

Run it by tacking the input on to the end like so:

```
In: LengthWhile[i=0;SortBy[#,-#&],#>i++&]&@{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
Out: 4
```

Comment: @MartinBüttner You're right, I can use `#>i++`. I tested some more cases. (And thanks for all the suggestions!)

Answer (score 4):

### SQL, <s>81</s> <s>94</s> 83

Given a table (I) of values (V), the following query will return h.  Tested in PostgreSQL and will also work in SQL Server.  **Edit** Make it return 0 rather than NULL.  Made better with a COUNT, thanks @nutki

```
SELECT COUNT(R)FROM(SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY V DESC)R,V FROM I)A WHERE R<=V
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8ef5b/1/0) example

Essentially it numbers the rows on a descending sort of the values.  Then it returns the maximum row number where the row number is greater than equal to the value.

Comment: You can use `COUNT(R)` instead of `COALESCE(MAX(R),0)` for a shorter fix for the NULL problem.

Comment: @nutki of course ... Thank you

Answer (score 4):

### R, <s>39</s> <s>35</s> 29

```
s=sort(i);sum(s>=length(s):1)
```

Given a vector of integers in i and using the logic of a reverse sort then returning the <s>length</s> of the vector where element number is less than s.  Thanks to @plannapus for the nice tip.

```
> i=c(23,42,12,92,39,46,23,56,31,12,43,23,54,23,56,73,35,73,42,12,10,15,35,23,12,42)
> s=sort(i);length(s[s>=length(s):1])
[1] 20
> i=c(0,0,0,0)
> s=sort(i);length(s[s>=length(s):1])
[1] 0
```

Comment: Nice! You can even shorten to 29 by directly summing the logical vector: `s=sort(i);sum(s>=length(s):1)`

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ñÍè>
```

[Try it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=8c3oPg&input=WzIzLDQyLDEyLDkyLDM5LDQ2LDIzLDU2LDMxLDEyLDQzLDIzLDU0LDIzLDU2LDczLDM1LDczLDQyLDEyLDEwLDE1LDM1LDIzLDEyLDQyXQ)

```
ñÍè>     :Implicit input of array
ñ        :Sort by
 Í       :  Subtracting from 2
  è      :Count the elements that are
   >     :  Greater than their 0-based indices
```

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 23 bytes

```
l~:I,),W%{_If>:!:+>}$0=
```

This takes the list as an array on STDIN, like

```
[23 42 12 92 39 46 23 56 31 12 43 23 54 23 56 73 35 73 42 12 10 15 35 23 12 42]
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

You can use this to run all test cases:

```
[0 0 0 0]
[12 312 33 12]
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
[22 33 1 2 4]
[1000 2 2 2]
[23 42 12 92 39 46 23 56 31 12 43 23 54 23 56 73 35 73 42 12 10 15 35 23 12 42]]
{:I,),W%{_If>:!:+>}$0=N}/
```

### Explanation

```
l~:I,),W%{_If>:!:+>}$0=
l~:I                    "Read input, evaluate, store in I.";
    ,                   "Get length of input N.";
     ),W%               "Create range from 0 to N, reverse.";
         {         }$   "Sort stably.";
          _I            "Duplicate candidate h, push input list.";
            f>          "Map each number to 1 if it's less or 0 otherwise.";
              :!        "Invert all results.";
                :+      "Sum them up.";
                  >     "Check if the sum is less than the candidate h.";
                     0= "Pick the first element.";
```

The logic is a bit backwards, but it saved a couple of bytes. Basically, the block passed to sort returns `0` for valid candidates and `1` otherwise. So the valid candidates come first in the sorted array. And because the sort is stable, and we begin with a list from N down to 1, this will return the largest valid h.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 5: 32 (30 + 2 for `-pa`)

```
#!perl -pa
$_=grep$_>$i++,sort{$b<=>$a}@F
```

Takes space separated input on STDIN:

```
perl hidx.pl <<<'1 2 3 4 5 6 7'
```

Comment: `sort{$b-$a}` saves 2 more

Answer (score 3):

## Python (63)

Basically a direct port of my J solution. Obviously, a lot longer, as one might imagine.

```
lambda x:sum(a>b for a,b in zip(sorted(x)[::-1],range(len(x))))
```

Comment: You can save some chars by using `enumerate`.

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 40

```
f s=[x-1|x<-[1..],x>sum[1|r<-s,r>=x]]!!0
```

this searches for the first number to not fit the scheme and returns it's predecessor.

Comment: 39 bytes with `until`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzNCoNADIRfJYceWhhhf5VC9UW2exCpVKoiroKHvvs2u5aQkPlmkncbPq9xjLGnUO/zNozX51E0R1OHfXLyuz6KgLU5/C3sXUciTu0wU03LOswbXWhqF@rJOYFcHuSkgk6tIVXWYAEDixJVAuo0GZvsCyF458omRxVf4s6pO0wJJrbklwkanaX5w0pD2zTPEykgbSJK57DynuIP "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby <s>44</s> 41

Recursive, more or less same strategy as xnor's Python solution:

```
f=->a,n=0{a.count{|x|x>n}<n+1?n:f[a,n+1]}
```

## Ruby 52

Non-recursive:

```
f=->a{a.size.downto(0).find{|x|a.count{|y|y>=x}>=x}}
```

"Stabby" lambda/anonymous functions, require Ruby 1.9 or newer. Call with e.g. `f[[22,33,1,2,4]]`

Answer (score 3):

## Bash + coreutils, 29

```
sort -nr|nl -s\>|bc|grep -c 0
```

Input taken from stdin as a newline-separated list.

- `sort` the integers in descending order
- `nl` prefixes each line with its 1-based line number, separating the line number and rest of the line with a greater-than `>`
- Arithmetically evaluate each line with `bc`.  Integers less than their line number result in 0.  Otherwise 1.
- `grep` counts the number of `0`s, i.e. the number of integers greater than or equal to `h`

#### Example

```
$ for i in {23,42,12,92,39,46,23,56,31,12,43,23,54,23,56,73,35,73,42,12,10,15,35,23,12,42}; do echo $i; done | ./atleasth.sh
20
$ for i in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}; do echo $i; done | ./atleasth.sh
4
$
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6) 48

Recursive solution.

```js
F=(l,h=-1)=>l.filter(v=>v>h).length>h?F(l,h+1):h
```

**Test** in FireFox/FireBug console

```js
;[
  [0,0,0,0],
  [12,312,33,12],
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
  [22,33,1,2,4],
  [1000,2,2,2],
  [23,42,12,92,39,46,23,56,31,12,43,23,54,23,56,73,35,73,42,12,10,15,35,23,12,42]
 ].forEach(l=>console.log(l,F(l)))
```

*Output*

```
[0, 0, 0, 0] 0
[12, 312, 33, 12] 4
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 4
[22, 33, 1, 2, 4] 3
[1000, 2, 2, 2] 2
[23, 42, 12, 92, 39, 46, 23, 56, 31, 12, 43, 23, 54, 23, 56, 73, 35, 73, 42, 12, 10, 15, 35, 23, 12, 42] 20
```

Comment: 47 bytes: `f=(l,h=0)=>l.map(v=>x+=v>h,x=0)&&x>h?f(l,h+1):h`. However, your solution would be 47 bytes too if you just change the `h=-1` to `h=0`.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 116 bytes.

Full class:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

class H{
    
    public static void main(String[]a){
        System.out.println(new H().f(Stream.of(a[0].split(",")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray()));
    }
    
    int i;
    
    int f(int[]n){
        Arrays.sort(n);
        i=n.length;
        Arrays.stream(n).forEach(a->i-=a<i?1:0);
        return i;
    }
}
```

Function:

```java
import java.util.*;int i;int f(int[]n){Arrays.sort(n);i=n.length;Arrays.stream(n).forEach(a->i-=a<i?1:0);return i;}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## APL, 12 characters

[`(+/⊢≥⍒)⊂∘⍒⌷⊢`](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%28+/%u22A2%u2265%u2352%29%u2282%u2218%u2352%u2337%u22A2%20%u22C4%20f%A8%284%u23740%29%2812%20312%2033%2012%29%28%u23737%29%2822%2033%201%202%204%29%281000%202%202%202%29%2823%2042%2012%2092%2039%2046%2023%2056%2031%2012%2043%2023%2054%2023%2056%2073%2035%2073%2042%2012%2010%2015%2035%2023%2012%2042%29&run)

Answer (score 2):

**C++ <s>815</s> 219 from (wc -c main.cpp)**

Alright here's some of the worst code I've ever written! :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;int main(int c,char** v){list<int>n(--c);int h=c;for(int&m:n)m=atoi(*(v+(h--)));n.sort();for(auto r=n.rbegin();r!=n.rend()&&*r++>++h;);cout<<(h==c?h:--h)<<endl;}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Jelly, 6 bytes

```
NỤỤ<’S
```

Explanation:

```
N           Negate (so that repeated elements won't mess up the second grade down)
 Ụ          Grade down
  Ụ         Twice.
   <’       Predicate, check for each element if the new one (after grading) is lower than original array (minus 1 on each element)
     S      Sum
```

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, <s>72</s> 59 bytes

My C++ solution looked pretty verbose, and the recursive nature made me think of Haskell, so here's my attempt:

```hs
a!i|i<foldr(\x s->s+fromEnum(i<x))0 a=a!(i+1)|1<2=i
H a=a!0
```

Explanation:

```hs
foldr (\x s -> s + fromEnum(i < x)) 0 a
```

I'm sure there's a shorter way to do this, because I'm pretty new to haskell, but basically it counts how many elements of `a` are less than `x`.

If this is greater than `i`, we can check `i+1`, otherwise, return `i`.

And the `H` function is so that we don't need to pass in `0` to `h`. It adds <s>10</s> 8 bytes, so I'm pretty sure there's a better way.

**-13 bytes** thanks to ovs

Comment: Instead of defining a the named function `H` the main function can be `flip a 0`, which can be shortened to ``(`h`0)``: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpLDoMgEADQfU8xiy4gjon2u5HuegptIrFMmRSQgCaevtS3flbnr3GukBqKGO3YyIMFDayYgDua3TuJYYNcP3JFafbPsHrB3SZls7fFmgD7F1y10rhsgIvXHEBBTBwWOAJB3@IJz3jBK97w/iq/iZz@5FJPMf4B "Haskell – Try It Online") (The `-cpp` is there to set up TIO in the same way we count the bytes here). Then you might want to have a look at these two tips: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/24670) and [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19259)

Comment: @ovs wdym about `flip a 0` and/or `\`h\`0`?

Comment: You don't need to name functions if you don't rely on a specific name, just like with Python `lambda`'s. But in Haskell `flip h 0` and ``(`h`0)`` are functions that do the same as your `H`, so ``(!0);a!i|...`` is a valid submission. (See the TIO link in my previous comment)

Answer (score 1):

### J, <s>15</s> 11 chars

(Current shortest J solution.)

```
   [:+/#\<:\:~

   ([:+/#\<:\:~) 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
4
```

Compares `<:` sorted list `\:~` elements with 1..n+1 `#\` and counts true comparisons `+/`.

Testing similarity against other J solution on 100 random test cases:

```
   */ (([:+/#\<:\:~) = ([:+/i.@#<\:~))"1 ?100 100$100
1
```

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 22 bytes

```
q~:Q,),{Q{1$>},,>!},W=
```

Takes the list as input:

```
[23 42 12 92 39 46 23 56 31 12 43 23  54 23 56 73 35 73 42 12 10 15 35 23 12 42]
```

Output:

```
20
```

[Try it here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 103

Anonymous function.

```cs
a=>{try{return a.OrderBy(b=>-b).Select((b,c)=>new{b,c}).First(b=>b.b<b.c+1).c;}catch{return a.Length;}}
```

Indented:

```cs
a =>
{
    try
    {
        return a.OrderBy(b => -b).Select((b, c) => new { b, c }).First(b => b.b < b.c + 1);
    }
    catch
    {
        return a.Length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JAGL](http://github.com/globby/jagl) Alpha 1.2 - 14

***Doesn't count*** because the 'C' reverse array functionality was added after the question, but am answering for fun anyway.

Assumes that the array is the first item on the stack, and puts the answer at the top of the stack.

```
0SJC{Sd@>+1}/S
```

To print, just add `P` at the end, adding a byte.

Explanation:

```
0               Push the number 0 (the counter)
 SJC            Swap to array, sort and reverse
    {Sd@>+1}/   For each item in the array, add 1 to counter if counter is less than item
             S  Swap counter to top of stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## GolfScript, 13 bytes

```
$-1%0\{1$>+}/
```

[Test this code online.](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=IyBUZXN0IGNhc2VzOgpbWzAgMCAwIDBdClsxMiAzMTIgMzMgMTJdClsxIDIgMyA0IDUgNiA3XQpbMjIgMzMgMSAyIDRdClsxMDAwIDIgMiAyXQpbMjMgNDIgMTIgOTIgMzkgNDYgMjMgNTYgMzEgMTIgNDMgMjMgNTQgMjMgNTYgNzMgMzUgNzMgNDIgMTIgMTAgMTUgMzUgMjMgMTIgNDJdXQoKIyBSdW4gY29kZSBvbiB0ZXN0IGNhc2VzLCBwcmludCBvdXRwdXQ6CnsgICQtMSUwXHsxJD4rfS8gIHB9Lw%3D%3D)<sup>1</sup>

Takes input as an array on the stack.  Uses the same algorithm as [feersum's Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42678), iterating over the numbers in the array and incrementing a counter from 0 until it equals or exceeds the current element of the array.

<sup>1) The online GolfScript server seems to be experiencing random timeouts again.  If the program times out for you, try re-running it.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, 22 bytes

ASCII representation:

```
Input L1:1:While Ans≤sum(Ans≥L1:Ans+1:End:Ans
```

Hex dump:

```
DC 5D 00 3E 31 3E D1 72 6D B6 72 6C 5D 00 3E 72 70 31 3E D4 3E 72
```

Gets a list as input. Starting from Ans=0, checks whether at least Ans+1 of the numbers are at least Ans+1. If so, increments Ans and loops again. If not, outputs Ans.

Answer (score 1):

## Reng v.3.2, 43 bytes

```
1#xk#yaïí'1ø ~n-1$\
1+)x(%:1,%1ex+y1-?^#y#x
```

[Try it here!](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/) This code can be split into three parts: initial, computational, and final.

### Initial

```
1#xk#yaïí'1ø
```

This stores `1` to `x`, the length of the input stack `k` to `y`, and gets all input (`aïí`) which is then sorted (`'`). `1ø` goes to the next line, i.e., the next part.

### Computational

```
1+)x(%:1,%1ex+y1-?^#y#x
```

Reng has no built-in for inequality. Thus, an algorithm must be implemented. The shortest algorithm I found for `a < b` is `%:1,%1e`; this looks like this:

```
Command | Stack
  ---   | a, b
   %    | a/b
   :    | a/b, a/b
   1    | a/b, a/b, 1
   ,    | a/b, (a/b)%1
   e    | (a/b) == ((a/b)%1)
```

I'm sure *that* cleared it up! Let me explain further. `x % 1`, i.e modulus with 1, maps `x` to `(-1,1)`. We know that `(a/b) % 1` is `a/b` when `a < b`. Thus, this expression is equal to `a < b`.

However, this doesn't work quite as well because of problems with modulus with zero. So, we increment every member of the stack and the counter initially.

After we get the inequality Boolean on the stack, `x+` adds it to x, but leaves it on the stack for the moment. `y1-` decrements `y`, and `?^` goes up iff `y == 0` and we proceed to the final phase. Otherwise, we put `y-1` into `y` and the new `x` into `x`.

### Final

```
             ~n-1$\
```

This pops the residual `y-1` from the stack, decrements the result, outputs it, and ends the program.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
{Rā@O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/OuhIo4P////RRsY6JkY6hkY6lkY6xpY6JmY6QBFTMx1jQ5CgiTGYawIVNDfWMTYFkRAthgY6hqYgEaAsSLFRLAA)
or as a [Test Suite](https://tio.run/##LYyxDsIwDER3vqLqfEiO7aTqQhkQKxJr1QEkBiYGRib@rf8VzimybPnenf163@7PRy3n09R3@0PXT/VzXb/HS0WdBa2W3ZwUFm1IGhLc4cgoGKh1s0g9XBHhygqLOeUVRmZGeAFJLnwX0K1J/8PBYDnmdpIEKQdRa2Fdfg)

**Explanation**

```
{R      # sort descending
  ā@    # check each element if it's greater than or equal to its 1-based index
    O   # sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>41</s> 39 bytes

```scala
_.sorted.:\(0){(n,h)=>h+(n/(h+1)).sign}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7fSsMwFIfv@xS5TNyhzb92rNDBLgV9AhWJa2oqNS1LFGXs2etptouCHBI4v@98JwlHM5h5fPuwx0geTe@J/YnWt4EcpumcfZuBdDV56EN8uvfxpdkf/G8zv@ZhPEXb5vUz5exMPTjW7N2G@oK6jWAsD/27//q8zK3tiKOmRvmONR01eRyXbSybTr2Pg6eOckjFWFEQvsqFBLUcBUImqNcQkICGEirY/qPyquGMTkytTc45AqyE5FrDjRJfgx36O9AVYFJW@I0l1Cq1@hZuFahyua@K4CDKJZEqDd@28@wy/wE)

In Scala 2.13, [`signum`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/Int.html#signum:Int) was changed to [`sign`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Int.html#sign:T), so it's 2 bytes extra in TIO, which still uses Scala 2.10.

### [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 41 bytes

```scala
a=>a.max to(0,-1)find(b=>a.count(b<=)>=b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY49a8MwEIZ3/wqNUrgm@rJDQmTI2KF06Fg6yLZMXFzZSZQSKP3t7knOYCiHBPc@95x0rW1vp6H6dHUgL7bzxN2D882VHMfxJ/u2PWn35M2d3599@DDl6xi6wc/NZE1p11/2TsJAOTwJ1na@oVVM6@HmA60OhpWmYlPjWnKido/eipmWWpaNl86H3tMTqqkY22wIX@RCgopHgZAJ6iUEJKAhhwK2/6icNZzRiamlyTlHgJWQXGq4UeJrsEN/B7oATPICvxFDrVKrH@FWgcrjPSuCg8hjIlUafmzn2e/0Bw)

This isn't mine, it's just a modified version of Chad Retz's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42691/95792), but since they're not active anymore, I decided to put it here instead of commenting on it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 5 bytes

```
s₌Ṙż≥
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=s%E2%82%8C%E1%B9%98%C5%BC%E2%89%A5&inputs=%5B23%2C42%2C12%2C92%2C39%2C46%2C23%2C56%2C31%2C12%2C43%2C23%2C54%2C23%2C56%2C73%2C35%2C73%2C42%2C12%2C10%2C15%2C35%2C23%2C12%2C42%5D&header=&footer=)

A port of the 05AB1E answer. I originally had `ẏ'?<∑≤` + `-G`, which I kinda like more.

### Explained

```
s₌Ṙż≥
s     # sort the input list
 ₌Ṙż  # and push reversed(^) and range(1, len(^) + 1)
    ≥ # vectorise >= over ^ and input
      # -s sums that
```

```
ẏ'?<∑≤
ẏ       # The range [0, len(input))
 '      # with only elements where: (call each element N)
  ?<∑   #   the sum of all elements of the input greater than N
     ≤  #   is less than or equal to N
        # (this gets all h with at least h)
        # -G gets the biggest h from the possible h's
```

Answer (score 1):

### C++, 81 bytes

```cpp
int h(std::list<int>a,int i=0){int c=0;for(int x:a)c+=i<x;return i<c?h(a,i+1):i;}
```

Similar solution to most of the other ones.

Assuming that `<list>` is included.

Non-recursive solution (<s>85</s> 83 bytes):

```cpp
int h(std::list<int>a){for(int i=0,c;;i++){c=0;for(int x:a)c+=i<x;if(i>=c)return i;}}
```

It might be possible to put the `c` initialization outside the function (because that defaults to 0, and you also don't need the `int`, but it doesn't seem to work on TIO.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 57 bytes

```
FirstCase[Range[Length@#,0,-1],h_/;Count[#,k_/;k>=h]>=h]&
```

This is an anonymous function taking a list and returning an integer, like

```
FirstCase[Range[Length@#,0,-1],h_/;Count[#,k_/;k>=h]>=h]&@{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
```

Use this to check all test cases:

```
FirstCase[Range[Length@#,0,-1],h_/;Count[#,k_/;k>=h]>=h]& /@ {
  {0, 0, 0, 0},
  {12, 312, 33, 12},
  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
  {22, 33, 1, 2, 4},
  {1000, 2, 2, 2},
  {23, 42, 12, 92, 39, 46, 23, 56, 31, 12, 43, 23, 54, 23, 56, 73, 35,
    73, 42, 12, 10, 15, 35, 23, 12, 42}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 62

```
def h(a:Int*)=Range(a.size,-1,-1).find(b=>a.count(b<=)>=b).get
```

Answer (score 0):

### Java, 107

```
long f(java.util.ArrayList<Long>l){for(int i=0;;){long x=i++;l.removeIf(j->j<x);if(l.size()<x)return x-1;}}
```

Explanation:

```
long f(java.util.ArrayList<Long> l) {
    for(int i = 0;;) {
        long x = i;
        i++;
        l.removeIf(j -> j<x);
        if(l.size() < x)
            return x-1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
SPGf<~s
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PzjAPc2mrvj//2gjYx0TIx1DIx1LIx1jSx0TMx2giKmZjrEhSNDEGMw1gQqaG@sYm4JIiBZDAx1DU5AIUBak2CgWAA)

#### Explanation

Direct application of the definition:

```
SP    % Take input array implicitly. Sort in non-increasing order
Gf    % Push array of indices of nonzero entries of the input. This gives
      % [1 2 ... n] where n is input size
<~    % True for values of the sorted input that are >= those in [1 2 ... n]
s     % Sum. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 0):

## x86 machine code, 24 bytes

Hexdump:

```
53 8b c2 8b d8 52 39 44 91 fc 72 01 4b 4a 75 f6
5a 48 4b 7d ee 5b 40 c3
```

A function that takes a pointer to the list and its length; outputs the number.

C-compatible declaration:

```
int __fastcall hindex(int* list, int size);
```

Source code:

```
    // eax = h
    // ebx counts down from h to 0; if it gets to 0, we have found h
    // ecx = list
    // edx = array size
    push ebx;
    mov eax, edx;                   // h = size ... down to 0
h_loop:
    mov ebx, eax;                   // init the countdown
    push edx;
array_loop:
    cmp [ecx + edx * 4 - 4], eax;   // check 1 list element
    jb skip;
    dec ebx;
skip:
    dec edx;                        // go to next element
    jnz array_loop;
    pop edx;
    dec eax;                        // go to next h
    dec ebx;                        // compare the countdown to 0
    jge h_loop;                     // if it was 0 or less, stop
    pop ebx;
    inc eax;                        // undo going to next h
    ret;
```

It uses a peculiar way to compare a register with 0:

```
    dec ebx;
```

Here, if `ebx` was less or equal to 0, it will be negative now, and then we should stop the outer loop (`h_loop`). Otherwise, continue:

```
    jge h_loop;
```

There is a small price (1 byte) to pay for this trick: the loop control variable `h` (`eax`) has already been advanced. So this has to be undone after the loop ends:

```
    inc eax;
```

However, even with this price, this trick gives the code the proper `do-while` structure, which saves 2 bytes when compared to a `for` structure.

Answer (score 0):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 41 bytes

```
@(x)sum(cumprod(-sort(-x)>=(1:numel(x))))
```

This is an anonymous function.

[Try it at Ideone](http://ideone.com/QvtLod).

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 43 bytes

```arturo
$=>[0-1enumerate arrange&=>[2-&]=>[>&<=1+]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?Qfv8gH)