# Sum the odd square numbers less than N

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic

Write a [program or function](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2419) to **[output](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447) the sum of [the odd square numbers (OEIS #A016754)](http://oeis.org/A016754) less than an [input](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447) `n`**.

The first 44 numbers in the sequence are:

```
1, 9, 25, 49, 81, 121, 169, 225, 289, 361, 441, 529, 625, 729, 841, 961, 1089, 
1225, 1369, 1521, 1681, 1849, 2025, 2209, 2401, 2601, 2809, 3025, 3249, 3481, 
3721, 3969, 4225, 4489, 4761, 5041, 5329, 5625, 5929, 6241, 6561, 6889, 7225, 7569
```

The formula for the sequence is `a(n) = ( 2n + 1 ) ^ 2`.

#### Notes

- Your program's behaviour may be undefined for `n < 1` (that is, all valid inputs are `>= 1`.)

#### Test cases

```
1 => 0
2 => 1
9 => 1
10 => 10
9801 => 156849
9802 => 166650
10000 => 166650
```

Comment: Neither of the close reasons on this are valid reasons to close a challenge...

Answer (score 22):

## Jelly, 6 bytes

```
½Ċ|1c3
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=wr3EinwxYzM&input=&args=MTAwMDA) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=wr3EinwxYzM&input=&args=MSwgMiwgOSwgMTAsIDk4MDEsIDk4MDIsIDEwMDAw).

#### Background

For all positive integers **k**, we have **1² + 3² + ⋯ + (2k - 1)² = k(2k - 1)(2k +1) ÷ 3**.

Since there are **m C r = m! ÷ ((m-r)!r!)** **r**-combinations of a set of **m** elements, the above can be calculated as **(2k + 1) C 3 = (2k + 1)2k(2k - 1) ÷ 6 = k(2k - 1)(2k + 1) ÷ 3.**

To apply the formula, we must find the highest **2k + 1** such that **(2k - 1)² < n**. Ignoring the parity for a moment, we can compute the highest **m** such that **(m - 1)² < n** as **m = ceil(srqt(n))**. To conditionally increment **m** if it is even, simply compute **m | 1** (bitwise OR with **1**).

#### How it works

```
½Ċ|1c3  Main link. Argument: n

½       Compute the square root of n.
 Ċ      Round it up to the nearest integer.
  |1    Bitwise OR with 1 to get an odd number.
    c3  Compute (2k + 1) C 3 (combinations).
```

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ES6), 30 bytes

```
f=(n,i=1)=>n>i*i&&i*i+f(n,i+2)
```

31 bytes if `f(1)` needs to return zero instead of false:

```
f=(n,i=1)=>n>i*i?i*i+f(n,i+2):0
```

Answer (score 7):

### Haskell, 30 bytes

```haskell
f n=sum[x^2|x<-[1,3..n],x^2<n]
```

Surprisingly normal-looking.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>10</s> 8 bytes

Code:

```
<tLDÉÏnO
```

Explanation:

```
<         # Decrease by 1, giving a non-inclusive range.
 t        # Take the square root of the implicit input.
  L       # Generate a list from [1 ... sqrt(input - 1)].
   DÉÏ    # Keep the uneven integers of the list.
      n   # Square them all.
       O  # Take the sum of the list and print implicitly.
```

Might come in handy: `t;L·<nO`.

Uses **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=PHRMRMOJw49uTw&input=OTgwMQ).

Answer (score 4):

## C#, <strike>126</strike> 131 bytes

Edited version to conform with the new question:

```
class P{static void Main(){int x,s=0,n=int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());for(x=1;x*x<n;x+=2)s+=x*x;System.Console.Write(s);}}
```

Using hardcoded limit:

```
using System;namespace F{class P{static void Main(){int x,s=0;for(x=1;x<100;x+=2)s+=x*x;Console.Write(s);Console.Read();}}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf! The agreed-upon format for answer headers here is `# Language name, number bytes` for consistency.

Comment: Why do you `Console.Read` at the end?

Comment: `namespace`s aren't required for single files.

Comment: You also should be able to save a few bytes by doing `System.Console.Write(s);` if it works, and if you don't need the`Console.Read`.

Comment: I added the `Console.Read` so the user can actually see the result when the console window appears - I guess using other IDEs this isn't necessary (I'm using Visual Studio). Also, thanks to @somebody for letting me know that `namespace` isn't required for single files- you learn something new everyday!

Comment: @Thomas You can run your program with Ctrl+F5 in VS in which case the window will remain open after the program terminates.

Comment: @Thomas You could include your current solution to check validity, and use `class P{static void Main(){int x,s=0;for(x=1;x<100;x+=2)s+=x*x;System.Console.Write(s);}}` as your actual answer

Comment: You can put `int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine())` directly at the `n` in the check of the loop to safe some bytes. So it becomes `class P{static void Main(){int x,s=0;for(x=1;x*x<int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());x+=2)s+=x*x;System.Console.Write(s);}}`

Comment: @KevinCruijssen then its evaluated each time and you have to keep typing in `n`

Comment: Can save two bytes with `using static System.Console;class P{static void Main(){int s=0,i,n=int.Parse(ReadLine());for(i=1;i*i<n;i+=2)s+=i*i;Write(s);}}`

Answer (score 4):

## Jelly, 7

```
’½R²m2S
```

[Try it online](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCZwr1SwrJtMlM&input=&args=OTgwMQ) or try a [modified version](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCZwr1SwrJtMlMKw5Higqw&input=&args=WzEsIDksIDEwLCA5ODAxLCAxMDAwMF0) for multiple values

Shh... Dennis is sleeping...

Thanks to Sp3000 in chat for their help!

#### Explanation:

```
’½R²m2S
’           ##  Decrement to prevent off-by-one errors
 ½R²        ##  Square root, then floor and make a 1-indexed range, then square each value
    m2      ##  Take every other value, starting with the first
      S     ##  sum the result
```

Comment: Dennis is actually awake.

Comment: @Dennis Ahh! And alert too, apparently...

Comment: [One does not simply out-golf Dennis.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78158/34718) :P

Answer (score 4):

## R, <s>38</s> 36 bytes

```
function(n,x=(2*0:n+1)^2)sum(x[x<n])
```

@Giuseppe saved two bytes by moving `x` into the arguments list to save the curly braces. Cool idea!

Ungolfed

```
function(n, x = (2*(0:n) + 1)^2)  # enough odd squares (actually too many)
  sum(x[x < n])                   # subset on those small enough
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYfBCoMwEAXv@Yp33G0jJDlZiV8i9RII7MFVooH8fWpL5zDDlN4z4oBcNV2yK6ltM4WHm/TpeQ181o3a0qK@2Zi8F5BAFIm8RbB4WXh3Z3T@5/D9m38cMwxwFNGLMglz7x8)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: This site is awesome, thanks!

Comment: You should be able to save two bytes by moving `x` into a default function argument and then you can remove the braces.

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 15 Bytes

```
qi(mq,2%:)2f#1b
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qi(mq%2C2%25%3A)2f%231b%0A&input=9801)

Hardcoded 10000 solutions:

Martin's 12 byte solution:

```
99,2%:)2f#1b
```

My original 13 byte solution:

```
50,{2*)2#}%:+
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=50%2C%7B2*)2%23%7D%25%3A%2B)

Comment: Your code is 14 bytes (you had a trailing linefeed in the link), but I think it's not correct for input 9801, since the challenge asks for the squares *smaller* than the input.

Comment: @MartinButtner Yes, you're right. I'll see if I can find an elegant fix

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, 23 bytes

```
@(x)(x=1:2:(x-1)^.5)*x'
```

Testing:

```
[f(1); f(2); f(3); f(10); f(9801); f(9802); f(10000)]
ans =    
        0
        1
        1
       10
   156849
   166650
   166650
```

Answer (score 3):

## C, <s>51, 50</s> 48 bytes

```
f(n,s,i)int*s;{for(*s=0,i=1;i*i<n;i+=2)*s+=i*i;}
```

Because why not golf in one of the most verbose languages? (Hey, at least it's not Java!)

[Try it online!](https://ideone.com/0ZOFDd)

Full ungolfed program, with test I/O:

```
int main()
{
    int s;
    f(10, &s);
    printf("%d\n", s);
    char *foobar[1];
    gets(foobar);
}

f(n,s,i)int*s;{for(*s=0,i=1;i*i<n;i+=2)*s+=i*i;}
```

Comment: `most verbose languages` More golfy than Python, C#, LISP, Forth, etc, C is actually pretty good for golf

Comment: @cat I don't think it's more golfy than python. It's definitely better than java, rust and C#, but every python answer on this challenge is `< 50 bytes`. Also, there's a relevant meta post [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8798/golfing-class-of-a-language).

Answer (score 3):

### Actually, 7 bytes

```
√K1|3@█
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=4oiaSzF8M0Dilog&input=MTA)

Also for 7 bytes:

```
3,√K1|█
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=MyziiJpLMXzilog&input=MTA)

This uses the same formula as in Dennis's Jelly answer.

Explanation:

```
√K1|3@█
√K       push ceil(sqrt(n))
  1|     bitwise-OR with 1
    3@█  x C 3
```

Comment: Will the next one be called `Literally`?

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
qX^:9L)2^s
```

*EDIT (July 30, 2016): the linked code replaces `9L` by `1L` to adapt to recent changes in the language.*

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=cVheOjFMKTJecw&input=OTgwMg)

```
q    % Implicit input. Subtract 1
X^   % Square root
:    % Inclusive range from 1 to that
9L)  % Keep odd-indexed values only
2^   % Square
s    % Sum of array
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 10 bytes

```
s<#Qm^hyd2
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%3C%23Qm%5Ehyd2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A9%0A9801%0A9802%0A10000&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
s<#Qm^hyd2
    m          Map over the range of input (0 ... input - 1)
       yd      Double the number
      h        Add 1
     ^   2     Square it
 <#            Filter the resulting list on being less than
   Q           The input
s              Add up what's left
```

Comment: Alternative (10 byte): `s<#Q%2t^R2`

Answer (score 2):

## Mathcad, 31 "bytes"

[image]

Note that Mathcad uses keyboard shortcuts to enter several operators, including the definition and all programming operators.  For example, ctl-] enters a while loop - it cannot be typed and can only be entered using the keyboard shortcut or from the Programming toolbar.   "Bytes" are taken to be the number of keyboard operations needed to enter a Mathcad item (eg, variable name or operator).

As I have no chance of winning this competition, I thought I'd add a bit of variety with a direct formula version.

Comment: How is MathCAD scored? Where can I get it?

Comment: The explanation of scoring you give is kinda... flimsy, IMO

Comment: You need to make a meta question for the scoring of this language.

Comment: Meta question sounds good. Trying to give a non-flimsy explantion for the scoring would rapidly turn into War and Peace.

Answer (score 2):

## Racket, 57 bytes

```
(λ(n)(for/sum([m(map sqr(range 1 n 2))]#:when(< m n))m))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-hx`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>6</s> 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
¬o²ó
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWh4&code=rG%2by8w&input=NTA)

```
¬o²ó     :Implicit input of integer
¬        :Square root
 o       :Range [0,ceil(¬))
  ²      :Square each
   ó     :Uninterleave
         :Implicit output of sum of last element
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>128</s> <s>119</s> <s>117</s> <s>111</s> 49 bytes

```java
n->{int s=0,i=1;for(;i*i<n;i+=2)s+=i*i;return s;}
```

Based on [*@Thomas*' C# solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78142/52210).

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hVDBDoIwDL37FT1uKgQ4aeb8A71wNB7mnKYIhWzDxBC@HYd6NWvaJu17eX1ppZ4qaTtD1fUx6Vo5BweFNCwAkLyxN6UNHOfxswDN5k5chM0YKqTzyqOGIxBImCjZDzPFyWyNMhe31jKBS9yRwJUsuFvJMAlrfG8JnBgn8ZXp@ksdZH5qzxav0AQnrPQW6X46K/51Ub6cN03a9j7tAuJrYpRqlvOPp794EcG3ETzPYgKbLI9TiuiZEPz33nF6Aw)

```java
n->{           // Method with integer as both parameter and return-type
  int s=0,     //  Sum, starting at 0
      i=1;     //  Index-integer, starting at 1
  for(;i*i<n;  //  Loop as long as the square of `i` is smaller than the input
      i+=2)    //    After every iteration, increase `i` by 2
    s+=i*i;    //   Increase the sum by the square of `i`
  return s;}   //  Return the result-sum
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, <s>32</s> 31 bytes

```
 n#x=sum[x^2+n#(x+2)|x^2<n]
 (#1)
```

Usage example: `(#1) 9802` -> `166650`.

Edit: @xnor saved a byte, with a clever list comprehension. Thanks!

Comment: It's a byte shorter to cheat away the guard: `n#x=sum[x^2+n#(x+2)|x^2<n]`

Answer (score 1):

## Reng v.3.3, 36 bytes

```
0#ci#m1ø>$a+¡n~
:m%:1,eq^c2*1+²c1+#c
```

[Try it here!](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/)

### Explanation

#### 1: initialization

```
 0#ci#m1ø
```

Sets `c` to `0` (the counter) and the input `I` to the `m`ax. `1ø` goes to the next line.

#### 2: loop

```
:m%:1,eq^c2*1+²c1+#c
```

`:` duplicates the current value (the squared odd number) and [I `m` puts `m`ax down. [I used the less-than trick in another answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42661/at-least-h-with-at-least-h/77097#77097), which I use here. `%:1,e` checks if the STOS < TOS. If it is, `q^` goes up and breaks out of the loop. Otherwise:

```
         c2*1+²c1+#c
```

`c` puts the counter down, `2*` doubles it, `1+` adds one, and `²` squares it. `c1+#C` increments `c`, and the loop goes again.

#### 3: final

```
        >$a+¡n~
```

`$` drops the last value (greater than desired), `a+¡` adds until the stack's length is 1, `n~` outputs and terminates.

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 39 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i=1:+(i*i<n)and i*i+f(n,i+2)
```

If, for `n=1`, it's valid to output `False` rather than `0`, then we can avoid the base case conversion to get 37 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i=1:i*i<n and i*i+f(n,i+2)
```

It's strange that I haven't found a shorter way to get `0` for `i*i>=n` and nonzero otherwise. In Python 2, one still gets 39 bytes with

```python
f=lambda n,i=1:~-n/i/i and i*i+f(n,i+2)
```

Comment: `bool` is a subclass of `int` in Python, which means `False` is an acceptable value for `0`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [orlp's answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78162/45941)

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), <s>33</s> <s>32</s> 26 bytes

Adapted from [Dennis' code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78158/2605):

```
n->t=(1-n^.5)\2*2;(t-t^3)/6
```

My first idea (30 bytes), using a simple polynomial formula:

```
n->t=((n-1)^.5+1)\2;(4*t^3-t)/3
```

This is an efficient implementation, actually not very different from the ungolfed version I would write:

```
a(n)=
{
  my(t=ceil(sqrtint(n-1)/2));
  t*(4*t^2-1)/3;
}
```

An alternate implementation (37 bytes) which loops over each of the squares:

```
n->s=0;t=1;while(t^2<n,s+=t^2;t+=2);s
```

Another alternate solution (35 bytes) demonstrating summing without a temporary variable:

```
n->sum(k=1,((n-1)^.5+1)\2,(2*k-1)^2)
```

Yet another solution, not particularly competitive (40 bytes), using the [L<sup>2</sup> norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance). This would be better if there was support for vectors with step-size indices. (One could imagine the syntax `n->norml2([1..((n-1)^.5+1)\2..2])` which would drop 8 bytes.)

```
n->norml2(vector(((n-1)^.5+1)\2,k,2*k-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 38 bytes

```python
s=(1-input()**.5)//2*2;print(s-s**3)/6
```

Based off [Dennis's formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78158/202600), with `s==-2*k`. Outputs a float. In effect, the input is square rooted, decremented, then rounded up to the next even number.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 29 bytes

```
f(n,i=1)=i^2<n?i^2+f(n,i+2):0
```

This is a recursive function that accepts an integer and returns an integer.

We start an index at 1 and if its square is less than the input, we take the square and add the result of recusing on the index + 2, which ensures that even numbers are skipped, otherwise we return 0.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 26 bytes

```
x->sum((r=1:2:x-1)∩r.^2)
```

This constructs the range of all odd, positive integers below **n** and the array of the squares of the integers in that range, then computes the sum of the integers in both iterables.

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=ZiA9IHgtPnN1bSgocj0xOjI6eC0xKeKIqXIuXjIpCgpmb3IgeCBpbiAoMSwgMiwgOSwgMTAsIDk4MDEsIDk4MDIsIDEwMDAwKQogICAgcHJpbnRsbihmKHgpKQplbmQ&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, 97 bytes

```sql
SELECT NVL(SUM(v),0)FROM(SELECT POWER((LEVEL-1)*2+1,2)v FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<:1)WHERE v<:1;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 53 bytes

```
#(reduce +(map(fn[x](* x x))(range 1(Math/sqrt %)2)))
```

You can check it here: https://ideone.com/WKS4DA

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica 30 bytes

```
Total[Range[1,Sqrt[#-1],2]^2]&
```

This unnamed function squares all odd numbers less than the input (`Range[1,Sqrt[#-1],2]`) and adds them.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 64 bytes

```
function f($i){$a=0;for($k=-1;($k+=2)*$k<$i;$a+=$k*$k);echo $a;}
```

Expanded:

```
function f($i){
    $a=0;
    for($k=-1; ($k+=2)*$k<$i; $a+=$k*$k);
    echo $a;
}
```

On every iteration of the `for` loop, it will add 2 to k and check if k<sup>2</sup> is less than `$i`, if it is add k<sup>2</sup> to `$a`.

Answer (score 1):

## R, 60 bytes

```
function(n){i=s=0;while((2*i+1)^2<n){s=s+(2*i+1)^2;i=i+1};s}
```

Does exactly as described in challenge, including returning 0 for the n = 1 case.
Degolfed, ';' represents linebreak in R, ignored below:

```
function(n){         # Take input n
i = s = 0            # Declare integer and sum variables
while((2*i+1)^2 < n) # While the odd square is less than n
s = s + (2*i+1)^2    # Increase sum by odd square
i = i + 1            # Increase i by 1
s}                   # Return sum, end function expression
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `sm`, 5 bytes

```
~∷~∆²
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBc20iLCIiLCJ+4oi3fuKIhsKyIiwiIiwiMVxuMlxuOVxuMTBcbjk4MDFcbjk4MDJcbjEwMDAwIl0=)

```
~     # range 1..n-1 (due to m flag) filtered by
 ∷    # is odd
  ~   # filtered by
   ∆² # is a perfect square
      # sum is taken by s flag
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 11 bytes

```
3!1 OR>.@%:
```

Pretty straightforward. Uses the Dennis formula.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmux2ljRUME_yE7PQdUKIrJfkys1OSNfIU3BUMFIwVLB0EDB0sLAEEQYKRimmkBULVgAoQE)

Answer (score 1):

## [FunStack](https://github.com/dloscutoff/funstack) alpha, 46 bytes

```
Sum Greater? @0 takewhile Square Inc Double #N
```

Try it at [Replit](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/funstack)!

#### Explanation

Compute the infinite list of odd square numbers:

```
                  #N  Infinite list of natural numbers
           Double     Each times 2
       Inc            Each plus 1
Square                Each squared
```

Sum those that are less than the input:

```
                takewhile  Take elements from the list while this function is true:
             @0             First program argument
    Greater?                is greater than the list element
Sum                        Sum those elements
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 54 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY8xC8IwEIV3f8XTKXEojWixxQiODk7iJCKxplJJY0lOqIi/vbbqovWN3937jvOpMqq@HM46JaxUbnGvjzpDxmyytMQlE6ALLA43jHhQqJJVcl4NKx5kuSHt2H5meeCvRQ20xaJxMOVOPsHCOXXbrsnl9rTjCTY2J0jce2iivNeOWMYEh5QI@Tcdvaj4ofFfKsI3/nXE0/AtF5NoOo6708@RKIomYcfZpDMum1fIWDZYGAPSnpAqrz3KtnfsD9qtR@9RPwE)

```scala
def f(n:Int)=(1 to n by 2).map(x=>x*x).filter(_<n).sum
```

57 bytes version:

```scala
def f(n:Int)=(1 to n by 2).map(x=>x*x).takeWhile(_<n).sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S-`, 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ƭRœɗ²
```

#### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
⁻ƭRœɗ²S
```

Alternatively, a port of Dennis's Jelly answer:

```
ƭṃ1Æ|3c
```

##### Explanation

```python
ƭRœɗ²  # Implicit input
       # - flag decrements the input
ƭ      # Square root of (input - 1)
 R     # Pop and push [1..that]
  œɗ   # Only keep odd numbers
    ²  # Square each number in this list
       # S flag sums the list
       # Implicit output
```

```python
ƭṃ1Æ|3c  # Implicit input
ƭṃ       # Push ceil(sqrt(input))
  1Æ|    # Bitwise OR with 1
     3c  # Get nCr with r=3
         # Implicit output
```

##### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, <strike>61</strike> 49 bytes

```python
lambda n:sum(i*i for i in range(1,n,2)if i*i<n)
```

plenty of savings, thanks for helping me out

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! [Unnamed functions are acceptable too](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1501/should-function-literals-be-allowed-when-a-function-is-asked-for/1503#1503), so you can omit the `c` (unless you need it for recursion, which you don't).

Comment: @MartinBüttner okay thanks for the help

Comment: You can omit the square brackets. This makes it the sum of a generator, which still works.

Comment: `i**2` is longer than `i*i`, and you can shorten `if i**2<n else 0` by putting the condition at the end: `lambda n:sum(i*i for i in range(1,n,2)if i*i<n)`. You also don't have to show the old code, we can see that in the version history.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 49 bytes

This ended up being shorter than a `lambda`.

```python
x=input()
i=1;k=0
while i*i<x:k+=i*i;i+=2
print k
```

[**Try it online**](http://ideone.com/bgLnNK)

My shortest `lambda`, **53 bytes**:

```python
lambda x:sum((n-~n)**2for n in range(x)if(n-~n)**2<x)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python, <strike>42</strike> 38 bytes

```
f=lambda n,i=1:i*i<n and i*i+f(n,i+2)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 32 bytes

```
f=->n,i=1{i*i<n ?i*i+f[n,i+2]:0}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 7 bytes (noncompetitive)

Add up_to function which repeats until the rtn is above inp.

```
#}hX)Os
```

Explanation:

```
#   )   -  While rtn < input:
        -   i = 0
 }hX    -    rtn = ((i*2)+1)**2
        -   i+=1
     O  -  rtn[:-1]
      s - sum(^)
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%23%7DhX%29Os&input=10)

Answer (score 0):

## Factor, <s>58</s> 57 bytes

```
[| n | n 2 * iota [ 2 * 1 + 2^ ] map [ n < ] filter sum ]
```

Well, this was simpler than I thought!

```
[| n |       ! new local var n
    n 2 *    ! double n
    iota     ! fixnum>range
    [ 
        2 *  ! double 
        1 +  ! + 1
        2^  ! square
    ] map    ! each item in range(0, n*2)
    [ 
        n <  ! entries over n
    ] filter ! keep-only 
    sum ]    ! sum the resulting array
```

Unit tests, if you like:

```
{ 0 }  [ 1  sum-odds-lt ] unit-test
{ 1 }  [ 2  sum-odds-lt ] unit-test
{ 1 }  [ 9  sum-odds-lt ] unit-test
{ 10 } [ 10 sum-odds-lt ] unit-test
{ 156849 } [ 9801 sum-odds-lt ] unit-test 
{ 166650 } [ 9802 sum-odds-lt ] unit-test
{ 166650 } [ 10000 sum-odds-lt ] unit-test
```

Answer (score 0):

## bash + bc, 86 bytes

```
s=0
for((n=0;;n++));{
w=`bc<<<"(2*$n+1)^2"`
[ $w -ge $1 ]&&break;
s=$((s+w))
}
echo $s
```

This piece of code is quite self explaining, as it simply sums up the values. It is not quite a magic code, as formatting it properly helps... The stop condition is not in the header of the loop, but after evaluating the step and before adding, since here we have all the values we need without initalising them beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, <s>51</s> 50 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to TuukkaX.*

Not sure if I can golf this more...

```
$s=0;map{$_%2?$s+=$_**2:()}(1..(<>-1)**.5);print$s
```

`map` checks whether the current value in the array `[1.. sqrt(input-1)]` is odd or even. If it's odd, increase `$s` with the odd number squared.

Comment: I don't know Perl yet, but I'm quite sure you can use `.5`.

Comment: @TuukkaX Indeed it works (I never think of that to be honest.) :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
⁻√ř²ƧƩ
```

Port of [FryAmTheEggman's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78156/77078).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//UePuRx2zjs48tOnY8mMr//83NAACAA)

Answer (score 0):

## dc, 19 bytes

```dc
1-v1+2/dd+1+d2-**3/
```

This uses the closed-form formula `⅓k(2k+1)(2k-1)` for the largest `k` such that `(2k-1)² < n`

### Ungolfed version

As a full program:

```dc
#!/usr/bin/dc -f

?                   # input

1-v1+2/             # k
dd+1+d2-            # k, 2k+1, 2k-1
**3/                # multply

p                   # output
```